# Trying to send a dynamic payload (python)

Tags: python, request, payload

I have been trying to make a POST request. My code is working properly if I put the "contestId" manually, but I want to make it dynamic.

```py
payload = "{\"contestId\":\"dcaf641d-ff39-4bf9-b295-4eb13936410d\",\"contestType\": \"OverUnder\",\"direction\": \"moon\",\"wager\": \"1\"}"
```

[image: img]

Comment: post code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Use some string concatenation to insert the variable holding the contestID into the right position.

Answer (score 0):

Your payload is json, therefore use json:

```
contest_id = "dcaf641d-ff39-4bf9-b295-4eb13936410d"

payload = {"contestId": contest_id, "contestType": "OverUnder", "direction": "moon", "wager": "1"}
response = request.post(URL, json=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```